# Unable to change specific text color in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

Here is my code. It's a simple function and what I need to change the text color when it shows `Active` eventStatus:

```
function() {
    var diff, status;
    diff = moment().diff(date, 'days')
    if (diff > 0) {
      status = 'Ended';
    }
    if (diff < 0) {
      status = 'Pending';
    }
    if (diff === 0) {

      status = 'Active';


        //status.style.color = "#132111"

        // document.getElementById('greenActive').style.color = "green"
    }
    return status;
  }
```

**UPDATE**
HTML:

```
  <td id = "status-column"  >
      <span id="greenActive" >{{eventStatus}}</span>  
   </td>
```

I tried to use both 'status.style.color' and 'getElementById'. The result is that the data/text won't show up at all.

Anything I did wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: **document**.getElementById('greenActive').style.color = "green"; - If that does not work you need to show the relevant HTML and where/how your code is called.

Comment: @AlexK. It didn't work. Please see the updated html code.

Comment: For sure, when you try to change the color the element still doesn't exists on the DOM tree. So you need a deferred object to apply the color when the server async request ends.

Comment: To help you, you need to share a working example reproducing the issue, if not, this question will be closed soon as offtopic. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve || http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Your code working but as I said, you need to make sure to execute the code after DOM loaded

```js
(function() {
    var diff, status;
    diff = 0
    if (diff > 0) {
      status = 'Ended';
    }
    if (diff < 0) {
      status = 'Pending';
    }
    if (diff === 0) {

      status = 'Active';

        document.getElementById('greenActive').style.color = "green"
    }
    return status;
  })();
```

```html
  <td id = "status-column"  >
      <span id="greenActive" >{{eventStatus}}</span>  
   </td>
```

You need to make sure that document loaded and DOM element you are trying to modify is available before calling you function. You can see a demo of js modifying text colour working [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_color)

Answer (score 0):

```
function() {
var diff, status , statusColor = '';;
diff = moment().diff(date, 'days')
if (diff > 0) {
  status = 'Ended';
}
if (diff < 0) {
  status = 'Pending';
}
if (diff === 0) {

  status = 'Active';
  statusColor = '#5CB85C';


    //status.style.color = "#132111"

    // document.getElementById('greenActive').style.color = "green"
}
return <div style="background-color:'+statusColor+'">'+status+'</div>;
```

}

```
<td id = "status-column"  >
  <span id="greenActive" >{{eventStatus}}</span>
```